# PhoneGap Connection Error

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

Am working on Android using jQueryMobile and PhoneGap.

I left the app idle on the screen, I found an "Application Error" when I picked it up again. It said the connection to the server was unsuccessful. I had to force close the app in order to get it to open again.

I mentioned this code in my Activity:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

But still the problem exists!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bigger value then 60sec, emulator can be extremely slow.

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 360000);
```

I have a laptop with an i5 processor and it requires more then 60sec sometimes.